# what zone / region has Finland datacenter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wonder what zone / region has Finland data center? ON the moment i have got smallest ping to Frankfurt, Germany europe-west3, it is 34 ml. Finland data center is much more closer but it is not listed in regions. I would like take 3 years commitment discount, but i just am afraid that things change and i will be not be able change it for 3 years. How i understand the commitment discounts are zone based. My servers are for baltic region.

Thanks

Comment: When I google "gce zone finland" the very first document clearly describes the status of Finland.

Answer (score 1):

There are none yet. Google has not yet expanded into Finland. When they do, the new region will be [listed on their web site](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/).

Comment: It currently says they will expand into Finland in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

It is `europe-north1 (a,b,c)`, all zones and their locations are listed here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#locations